# jUnit test cases for Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit, threadpool

I know testing threads is always a challenge. In addition to testing Thread i just got one question. Is  there a way we can test the threads and can figure out which data went through which thread using jUnit.
Assume there n number of threads which are storing the data to a table. Can we figure out that which row of data was stored by which thread.

**Updated**

```
public void storePrescription(List<Prescription> payload) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (Prescription presciption : payload) {
        Runnable runnable = new PrescriptionThread(presciption, prescriptionService);
        executorService.execute(runnable);
    }
    executorService.shutdown();

    while(!executorService.isTerminated()) {}
}
```

Thread Class

```
public class PrescriptionThread implements Runnable{

private PrescriptionService presServ;

private  Prescription pres ;

public PrescriptionThread(Prescription pres, PrescriptionService prescriptionService) {
    this.pres = pres;
    this.presServ = prescriptionService;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    presServ.savePrescription(pres);
}
}
```

Comment: Naming `Runnable`s Thread is confusing (you have `PrescriptionThread`) and incorrect. Traditionally such classes are called `workers` as in `PrescriptionWorker`

Comment: @DavidSoroko You mean to say it's better to use Thread instead of Runnable

Comment: No, I mean the names you give to your Runnables should not include the word 'thread'.

Comment: Ok. I got . i have changed that as Worker, Thanks for  the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Most straitforward way would be logging the current thread name or id and the data it's processing.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestLogThreadName.class);
String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
logger.trace("processing data (" + data + ") with Thread " + currentThreadName);
```

Even though this would be the most easy to implement, it still depends on the data size, because the generated log file could be huge and hard to read.

What aspect are you trying to monitoring, if it's hardware resources related like cpu or memory, maybe you could try using some tool that OS provided.

**updated:**

first create a util class for writing log,

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class LogThreadNameUtil{

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogThreadNameUtil.class);

    public static void log(String threadName
        , Prescription prescription){
        //you have to get specific 
        //field value from prescription or override toString()
        logger.trace("processing data (" + prescription 
            + ") with Thread " + currentThreadName);
    }
}
```

then call the log util from the your runner,

```
public class PrescriptionThread implements Runnable{

private PrescriptionService presServ;

private  Prescription pres ;

public PrescriptionThread(Prescription pres, PrescriptionService prescriptionService) {
    this.pres = pres;
    this.presServ = prescriptionService;
}

@Override
public void run() {
        presServ.savePrescription(pres);
        LogThreadNameUtil.log(Thread.currentThread().getName(), pres);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i have this for the above code. Code in the updated part.

Comment: What ever you all are saying in fine. If I have to do it while running. But I want to test it while Unit Test cases.

Comment: did you mean you wanna log the thread name and the 'Prescription" during unit test? Could you post you unit test code for more context?

Comment: if you instantiate and start the thread from unit test, it should log the thread information with be code above, cause the log invocation line is inside the run method. so it dosen't matter how you start the thread.

Comment: the prob here is I can't keep the log inside the run. Because I don't want it to be tracked when application is running. Only from jUnit o want to track the each thread.   Is this possible?..

Comment: so you need to monitor thread without any modification in the 'PrescribtionWorker' ? you chould try to do this with reflection, first get all the threads with 'Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();'  pick the threads that you want to monitoring, then using reflection to fetch the Runnable object it contains, then you can log the Prescription info and thread name. that's the best that I can work out without any edit in the source code, or maybe just log the info inside the thread but dial down the log level to trace? after all that's what log level was for.

Comment: I actually tried the reflection aproach, it's really complicated with the ThreadPoolExecutor, cause all the dynamic assigned runnable, it would be easier if it's plain old thread. hope you would find better solution that that :)

Comment: or maybe monitoring the objects with JMX, but still that require implementing jmx interfaces too.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your workers in whatever way makes sense to you and log the in the `run` method as below:

```
public class PrescriptionThread implements Runnable{

    private PrescriptionService presServ;
    private  Prescription pres ;
    private  String name ;

    public PrescriptionThread(Prescription pres, PrescriptionService prescriptionService, String name) {
        this.pres = pres;
        this.presServ = prescriptionService;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        presServ.savePrescription(pres);
        LOG.info("Worker-" + name + " saved: " + pres);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am actually try the test this in jUnit. And it should verify the same thing.